# configure jupyter notebook config file for a virtual environment to save .py files

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to run python on virtaual env, my virtual environment is activated, I want to modify the jypter notebook file config to want to save the script in form of .py evrytime that i created an ipynb.

Let's notice that on my venv i tried this command to generate the config file :

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

the file is created in the main of my machine

```
/Users/paulbergan/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

which is not what i want .

So i need to access the config file crreated in the venv and add these rows below to do the approriate save (ipynb and py):

```
 c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class="jupytext.TextFileContentsManager"
 c.ContentsManager.formats = "ipynb,py"
```